# Proximity in Solr.Net - yields no results

Tags: solr, solrnet

How to do this simple query in solr.net? I'm on it for 3 hours now...

```
Text:"Thank you"~10
```

The below returns no results:

```
var query = new SolrQueryByField("Text", "\"Thank you\"~10");
```

From Fiddler:

```
GET /solr/new_core/select?rows=10&q=Text%3a%22%5c%22Thank+you%5c%22%5c%7e10%22&? HTTP/1.1
```

From *schema.xml*:

```xml
<field name="Text" type="text_auto" indexed="true" termVectors="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />

<fieldType class="solr.TextField" name="text_auto" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" maxShingleSize="4" outputUnigrams="true"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: whats the schema.xml? how are you indexing it? Share the fieldType used for the field 'Text'

Comment: the above analyser is for indexing(assuming as i dont see type) and whats the one for query? Did you check the output on the solr analysis page?

Comment: can you try by removing the "ShingleFilterFactory" ? I tried and its working...or can you check the output after the "ShingleFilterFactory" on analysis page.

Comment: try using this <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" maxShingleSize="2" outputUnigrams="true"/>